# How to calculate a percentage of a percentage in a single query

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

Using databricks SQL I created a table that looks like this:

| tablename | RunDate | Quality | qaflag | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blah | 2022-06-02 | bronze | 1 | Passed |
| blah1 | 2022-06-02 | silver | -1 | failed |

I can write a query that will calculate the percentage of each Quality type in the table
e.i.

```
SELECT Quality, 
       COUNT(Status)*100/(SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM test) as Percentage
FROM test
GROUP BY Quality
```

That will give me this output:

| Quality | PercentageTotal |
| --- | --- |
| Silver | 64 |
| Gold | 3 |
| Bronze | 33 |

I would like to add a percentage of each Quality that passed or failed as well.
Basically, I need to try to get it to look like this:

| Quality | PercentageTotal | PercentagePassed | PercentageFailed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Silver | 64 | 99 | 1 |
| Gold | 3 | 87 | 3 |
| Bronze | 33 | 60 | 40 |

What the table is saying is:
Silver Tables constitute 64 percent of all tables tested, and 99 percent of them passed and 1 percent failed. (and so on for the other ones)

I am stuck at trying to figure out how to calculate the PercentagePassed/Failed can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to a window function with `distinct` to eliminate your `group by` needs, then use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT distinct Quality
    , count(Status) over (partition by Quality) * 100 / count(status) over (partition by null) PercentageTotal
    , count(case when Status = 'Passed' then 1 end) over (partition by Quality) * 100 / count(status) over (partition by Quality) PercentagePassed
    , count(case when Status = 'Failed' then 1 end) over (partition by Quality) * 100 / count(status) over (partition by Quality) PercentageFailed
FROM test
```

You may want to consider switching to another data type that will support decimals, but I've left it as is for your example.